# SpringMVC: how to specify the date format in jsp pages

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have a model defined as follows:

```
public class TM
{
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
    Date date;

    public Date getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

I have a controller defined as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test")
public ModelAndView func(ModelAndView mav)
{
    TM tm = new TM();
    tm.setDate(new Date());
    mav.addObject("obj", tm);
    mav.setViewName("test/view.jsp");
    return mav;
}
```

File `view.jsp`:

```
${obj.date}
```

It outputs `Wed Jan 14 20:00:46 CST 2015`, rather than what I expected in "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss" format

SpringMVC's annotation `@DateTimeFormat` doen't work for me.

I know I can achieve the same thing using `<fmt:formatDate...` in the jsp page, but that isn't my prefered way since I have to add `<fmt:formatDate...` wherever I have to print a `Date` object or `TM` object.

I am just wondering how to achieve this using sping's `@DateTimeFormat`?

Comment: Use JodaDate firstly, it is much more better the Date. In that, you can get set the precision level and format you want. If you want I can create an answer for you, but you can find it with simple google

Comment: @WeareBorg is it possible with Java's built in Date class?

Comment: I have created an answer, check it out, let me know in comments if any doubts.

Comment: It does work, but only if you use it properly, you aren't using it properly. The date formatting will only work if you use it with the spring form tags. You are just using EL to print the value of the field, which is basically `Date.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<fmt:formatDate value="${obj.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
```

Comment: thx for your quick reply, but I have just updated my question, I do know I can achieve this using jstl, but I am wondering how to achieve this using springmvc

Comment: Well, why don't you want to user JSTL? What are you using in your JSP's? Presuming you are using JSP.

Comment: Do you use any template engine, such as velocity?

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

to dispatcher-servlet.xml.

And put this begining of the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:device="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mobile/device"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mobile/device http://www.springframework.org/schema/mobile/device/spring-mobile-device-1.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you GO :

You can format your date using SimpleDateFormat. Check ou JavaDocs, just a bit of sample.

```
**String oldstring = "2011-01-18 00:00:00.0";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(oldstring);**

String newstring = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
System.out.println(newstring); // 2011-01-18
```